# Image segmentation for several similar images

Tags: image, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a slightly strange question. I made a nude photo every week since I started going to the gym about 6 months ago and I want to see how I changed in a video. The problem is that I didn't make them in front of a blue wall or something like that, but just in my room. Now I want to extract me from it and create a video from it. I could do it by hand, but that would be a lot of work and it wouldn't be half as much fun. There are several problems:

- The room looks similar, but not everything in the background is exactly the same always
- The lighting is of the room very different
- The lighting of myself is different
- The place where I took the photos is almost the same (I tried my best) but not quite, so everything is displaced differently by a few pixels on every photo
- The angle is also a little different

I want to be able to extract me from every photo and automatically adjust the lighting such that it looks as similar as possible.

I know an algorithm that works for a similar problem: I have a video of just the background and one video where a person walks through the scene. I can then calculate the mean m RGB vector of every pixel in the background-only video and build the covariance matrix C and for the real video, I extract every pixel x where (x-m)'C(x-m) is larger than some threshold. But I guess that works if the lighting of the background changes slightly, but I guess it doesn't work for different angles and different displacement, so I guess I need an improvement.

I have very good programming skills and basic knowledge about image processing, so I am probably able to understand papers on the topic etc. I just don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

The image segmentation task where pixels can belong to two classes, object and background, is usually called "thresholding". There are several algorithms available, but almost every image processing library implements Otsu's method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_Method) by default. If there is uneven lightning, you can try a class of algorithms that use several threshold values, one for each subset of pixels in the image, instead of only one for the whole image. These methods are known as "adaptive thresholding"/"local thresholding" in the literature and emerged from OCR and medical research. You may need to pre-process/post-process your results with some morphological filters to eliminate noise.

Here's a great blog post about a similar segmentation task, in MATLAB: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/10/08/the-two-amigos/

If you still don't get good results, search the literature for "background subtraction" for more sophisticated algorithms that are not based on intensity thresholds.